# Transforming xml using XmlDataSource conrol in asp.net 2.0

Tags: .net, xml, xslt, transform, xmldatasource

Using ASP.NET 2.0 i carried out below steps

**book.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<greeting>
  Hello, World!
</greeting>
```

**data.xsl**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="greeting"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="greeting">
    <h1>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </h1>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Page**

```
<div>
   <asp:XmlDataSource runat="server" EnableCaching="false" ID="xmlDs" DataFile="~/book.xml" TransformFile="~/data.xsl"></asp:XmlDataSource>
</div>
```

Sadly nothing appears in the page, I expected a output `Hello, World!`. So what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the control you're looking for is `<asp:Xml>`:

```
<div>
    <asp:Xml id="test" DocumentSource="book.xml" TransformSource="data.xsl" runat="server"/>
</div>
```

XmlDataSource is generally used in combination with other data bound controls like TreeViews or Repeaters